# How to install the StackExchange Data Dump Viewer?

Tags: software-installation

How do I install the [StackExchange Data Dump Viewer](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/708/stackexchange-data-dump-viewer-a-desktop-tool-for-viewing-the-stackexchange-da)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Firstly open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).
- Install Bazaar (`bzr`) and other required dependencies by pasting this (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) in the terminal:

  ```bash
  sudo apt-get install bzr qt4-qmake libqt4-dev libqtwebkit-dev
  ```
- Get all the code:

  ```
  bzr branch lp:aubrowser
  ```
- Now navigate into the directory:

  ```
  cd aubrowser
  ```
- Now compile the code:

  ```
  ./compile_everything
  ```
- Now start the conversion wizard:

  ```
  convert/convert
  ```
- A window will open. Paste `data/posts.xml` then follow through the wizard.

  [image: Wizard screenshot]
- Now close the terminal, open Nautilus and browse to the `aubrowser` folder inside your home folder and run the `AskUbuntuBrowser` file (by double clicking on it).

  [image: Nautilus]
- Tada!

  [image: StackExchange Data Dump Viewer Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

See the [readme](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~george-edison55/aubrowser/trunk/view/head:/README) in the installation file. 1st part:

```
StackExchange Data Dump Browser is a small Qt-based application 
designed to make it easy to view the contents of StackExchange data dumps 
when you have no active Internet connection.

Building the application (the easy way):

1. Open a terminal and navigate to the root directory of the repository.
2. Type `./compile_everything`
3. Run `convert/convert` to run the conversion wizard. 
When prompted for the location of the data dump files, enter 'data/posts.xml'.
```

[Here](https://launchpad.net/aubrowser) you can find the package.

Comment: Well the author forgot to mention the dependencies and how to get the code .

Comment: Indeed he did! tsk tsk. Excellent answer alaukik.

Comment: @Alaukik: Oops :) Good answer, though.